# Python zip unequal length lists while evenly spreading out shorter lists

Tags: python, python-zip

**Problem statement:** A row of 20 plants need to be sprayed with chemical doses. 20 doses of chemical A each go on one of the 20 plants. Chemical B, C, and D have fewer than 20 doses each. They need to be sprayed evenly across some of the 20 plants such that, to the best of our ability, they are equally spaced among plants.

e.g. Input doses:

```
chemical_a = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a]
chemical_b = [b, b, b]
chemical_c = [c, c]
chemical_d = [d]
```

Desired result:

```
[a, a, a, ab, a, ac, a, a, a, abd, a, a, a, a, ac, a, ab, a, a, a]
```

As you can see, `chemical_b` is spaced with 3 unfilled `b` spots either side of it - except for the middle dose which has 2 on one side and 3 on the other. Such scenarios are inevitable. If `chemical_d` with 19 doses was introduced, one of plants would miss out - it doesn't really matter which plant that is.

*How would you solve this problem using Python 3?*

Comment: `How would you solve this problem` - try writing some code and come back to us when you face problems. Good luck!

Comment: You must have forgotten to show your own attempts.

Comment: If I had something good to share I would - but I am relying on someone smarter than me to provide - flex your muscles boys.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion!

```
import math

def spread(long, short):
  if long == 1 and short == 1:
    return [True]
  
  if long % 2 == 0:
    left = right = int(long / 2)
    if short == 1:
      return [False] * (left - 1) + [True] + [False] * right # default to fewer lefts if even
    elif short % 2 == 0:
      short = int(short / 2)
      return spread(left, short) + spread(right, short)
    else:
      short = math.floor(short / 2)
      return spread(left - 1, short) + [True] + spread(right, short) # default to fewer lefts if even
  else:
    left = right = math.floor(long / 2)
    if short == 1:
      return [False] * left + [True] + [False] * right
    elif short % 2 == 0:
      short = int(short / 2)
      return spread(left, short) + [False] + spread(right, short)
    else:
      short = math.floor(short / 2)
      return spread(left, short) + [True] + spread(right, short)
    
chemical_a = 20
chemical_b = 3
chemical_c = 2
chemical_d = 1

def transform(x, type):
  if x:
    return type
  else:
    return ''

result_a = map(transform, spread(chemical_a, chemical_a), chemical_a * 'a')
result_b = map(transform, spread(chemical_a, chemical_b), chemical_a * 'b')
result_c = map(transform, spread(chemical_a, chemical_c), chemical_a * 'c')
result_d = map(transform, spread(chemical_a, chemical_d), chemical_a * 'd')

def convertTuple(tup):
    st = ''.join(map(str, tup))
    return st

print(list(map(convertTuple, zip(result_a, result_b, result_c, result_d))))
```

Result:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'abc', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'abd', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'abc', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```